# Using equals and == on LocalDate Object

Tags: java

I have the following code :

```
LocalDate one = LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 1);
LocalDate two = LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 1);
System.out.println(one.equals(two)); // true since contents are same
System.out.println(one == two); // false since references are diff
LocalDate newone = one.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
System.out.println(newone.equals(one));// true since contents are still same
System.out.println(newone == one); //-4- why true here
```

The question is why at 4 it is giving true as LocalDate objects are immutable so changing one with TemporalAdjuster would give a new LocalDate Object. If the contents of newone and one are not same than

```
newone == one returns false
```

Kindly update this behaviour.
Thanks

Comment: I did not look at the code, but `nextOrSame` has the word "same" in it, so...

Comment: Obviously, this particular adjustment does not change the object as 2016-01-01 is already Friday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the code of `TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame`:

```
public static TemporalAdjuster nextOrSame(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
    int dowValue = dayOfWeek.getValue();
    return (temporal) -> {
        int calDow = temporal.get(DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (calDow == dowValue) {
            return temporal;  // <-- returns the original object!
        }
        int daysDiff = calDow - dowValue;
        return temporal.plus(daysDiff >= 0 ? 7 - daysDiff : -daysDiff, DAYS);
    };
}
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#nextOrSame-java.time.DayOfWeek-) (emphasis mine):

> Returns the next-or-same day-of-week adjuster, which adjusts the date to the first occurrence of the specified day-of-week after the date being adjusted unless it is already on that day in which case **the same object is returned**.

So if no adjustment is needed (because Jan 1. 2016 *was* a Friday) then *the same* object is returned.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36042324/642706) is correct.

## Avoid Reference Equality Tests on Value-Based Objects

I will just add that generally speaking, one should avoid using `==` in Java as that simply tests for reference equality, asking if two reference variables point to the very same object allocated in memory. Nearly always a call to `equals` or a particular class’ own equality-test method is appropriate.

Specifically, the [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class doc warns *against* doing this reference equality test on objects of such a [value-based](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html) class.

> This is a value-based class; use of identity-sensitive operations (including reference equality (==), identity hash code, or synchronization) on instances of LocalDate may have unpredictable results and should be avoided. The equals method should be used for comparisons.

While I understand user2779311 seems to have intended this reference equality test as an intellectual exercise, I want to point out that such a test is generally inappropriate in production code.

Answer (score -2):

You can refer the docs here [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-)

```
public LocalDate with(TemporalAdjuster adjuster)
```

Returns an adjusted copy of this date.

Thus object which is returned is copy of object thus reference is same thus your output returns true.

Comment: It it were a _copy_ in this case, then `==` would _not_ return true.